# Distributing jar file using launch4j

Tags: java, deployment, runtime-error, launch4j, classnotfound

I have created a jar file and linked it to .exe file using the launch4j, it was working in the computer that I created the software, but when i try to distribute the software, The .exe file or .jar file or .jnlp file, none are working. When I double click the .exe file, I will get error

```
package.mainclass not found. Program will exit
```

how to find the error, if it is working in my computer and not working when i distribute it?

Comment: *"The .exe file or .jar file or .jnlp file,.."*  JNLP as in Java Web Start?  Provide more details specific to that and I might be able to help you sort it out.

Comment: i have created a project and buid a jar file using the netbeans. and then i used launch4j software to make it as .exe file, where everything works fine in my computer, but when i distrubte/ run in other computer, I am facing the above error.

Comment: Sure, I saw that the first time you wrote it, in the question.  Did you read what I wrote in my comment?  To put 'not too fine a point' on it -- I don't give a toss if it fails in Launch4J, but might help you fix the JWS.

Comment: How did you configure Launch4J?  Make sure you _don't_ tick the "don't wrap the JAR" box.

Comment: i figure out the error, error -> i am running the software with wrong JRE